# How to generate Cognito access_token via AWS CLI (works via CURL) with just client_id and secret_id?

Tags: amazon-cognito

This works great:

```
client_id=XXX
client_secret=YYY
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${client_id}&client_secret=${client_secret}" \
 "https://MyEndPoint/oauth2/token"
```

I get back a nice payload:

```
{
  "access_token": "***",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

How can I get that payload via AWS CLI?

I only have these 3 pieces of data:

- User Pool ID
- Client ID
- Client Secret

There is no username or password.

I thought something like this would work, but it doesn't

```
aws cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth \
  --user-pool-id <user_pool_id> \
  --client-id <client_id> \
  --auth-flow ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH \
  --auth-parameters USERNAME=<client_id>,SECRET_HASH=<client_secret>
```

So I thought the secret hash is something like this:

```
Base64 ( HMAC_SHA256 ( "Client Secret Key", "Username" + "Client Id" ) )
```

But there is no username at all. I only have those 3 pieces of data, and username is not one of them.

So how can I simulate that curl command (which works just fine) with AWS CLI?
Thanks!